# GUI for a weekly schedule

Tags: gui-design

I am currently working on a weekly schedule for sport teams and everything have been going smoothly UX wise. The UI part, for some reason, is a bit more tricky for me this time around. The creation and edit part of the schedule works really well, but the thing that is working my head in is the showcase of the schedule.

When users visit a team they will see various information like the prices, description, location etc. and the schedule. I need some help and some suggestions as to how I can show the teams weekly schedule in a modern and intuitive way.

So my question is, do you guys have any good ideas and/or examples of a weekly schedule that I can use as an anchor point?

The current design looks like this:

[image]

Comment: At first glance, without knowing the requirements of your target app/audience, there doesn't appear to be anything drastically _wrong_ with your example, but presumably you think there is, otherwise you wouldn't be asking this question. Can you add some more details about _why_ you think what you've got so far isn't good enough?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my current schedule. I just don't love it. I've tested it along with some other features and the schedule's functionality tested well, but the visual appearance got a lesser score than my requirement. So I am looking to "spice it up" and make it more appareling. So I am looking for some inspiration, some website, app etc. that could give me a new take on how to display the information without breaking the functionality too much.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Sample UI]

As per my understanding of this use case, you can check out this sample UI.

Comment: The users don't need any other information other than the day of the week and the time. Rest of the information regarding the team is next to the schedule on a separate card. I've been trying to find other sites that uses a team schedule, but I haven't had much success unfortunately. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

A great example which can cover all scenarios of schedules is the [Google Calendar website](https://www.google.com/calendar). It will be very helpful if you visit google calendar and see all types of variations google calendar has to offer.

I tried to change your schedule view keeping in view the google's weekly schedule and it turned out something like the wire-frame given below:

[image]

Comment: Yeah I've been looking a lot at googles calendars and my UI resembles it a lot. I've been trying, with limited resources, to dig deeper, but I haven't had much success. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it matters to your specific use case, but in your current design, users can't see at a glance exactly when and how long each session will be. To know that they need to read the exact time, and calculate the duration. Also sessions that occur at different times of the day appear all on the top line. This makes it difficult for the user to get an overall picture of when things happen. It might be the reason why they didn't like it as much, without being able to articulate the exact reason why.

In most calendars, each day has a certain length, and you can visually determine when and how long events are, just by looking at the location and size of the rectangle, without reading the exact time.

A feature that might be useful would be to add this session to their own calendar. You could add a small icon to allow the user to do that.